# Get params from response with Python

Tags: python, http, url, request, response

When I enter certain page with my browser, some params are added. For example the URL changes from *https://www.mypage.com/subpage* to *https://www.mypage.com/subpage/productId=12345*.

I want to do a request to this url and get the url with the param (productId=12345) added. I have tried to get the url from the response, but it returns the same url, and to get the history, but there is no redirection.

```
url = "https://www.mypage.com/subpage"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.history)
#[]
```

Comment: Well, if the server does not return a redirection, there is not much you can do. If you look at the developer tools in your browser, do you find evidence that the redirect is done using HTTP redirects instead of using javascript? If the redirect is done using javascript, there is no way for `requests` to know about that.

Comment: @teprrr, could you provide a link to the real site with described behavior for code testing purpose? I think there may be something related with cookies.

Comment: Hi Grey, I'm not the original poster but my understanding is that the OP's `subpage` performs this forward using javascript rather than HTTP headers. To check that `requests.get()`'s forward behavior works, you can try http://google.com which does an HTTP 301 forward to its www subdomain.